# audio processing in iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, filter

I am writing an iPhone application to apply filters to audio input and output the result in real time.

I am new to audio processing but using audiounit, the correct approach?

I found out how to output data using audiounit but couldn’t figure out how to capture input audio.

Is there a sample application showing how to connect input and output using audiounit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app from apple. Audio unit is a very complex framework to use. I suggest you look at the AVFoundation framework if it suits your need. I hope it helps you.